# The easiest way to check if localStorage has a value in AngularJS routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Many tutorials in web have a little bit strange and huge logic of angularJS conditional routings...

i need something very simple:

just one component to check, if localStorage has authFlag as true, then something like:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'views/app.html',
          controller: 'AppCtrl'
      })
      .when('/articles', {
          templateUrl: 'views/articles.html',
          controller: 'ArticlesCtrl',
          conditions: { isAuth }
      })
      .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
      });
});
```

how is it better to do? to check if authFlag is in localStorage, if not, then root to '/' ?

Comment: This just configures the routes.  The logic that decides which route to redirect to does not belong here. That logic should be inside of your controller.

Comment: @pixelbits how to code such logic?

Comment: I would handle re-directs related to login security on the server. It should be handled server-side.

Comment: @pixelbits no, ui must have routing too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add resolve, then in the resolve funciton, add check for the local storage,
and route to "/" if not:

in the resolve funciton add the following code

```
resolve:{
    data:  function(){
        var result = window.localStorage.getItem("authFlag");

        if (result)
        {
            // do whatever you want to do
        }
        else
        {
            $location.path("/");
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: `result` will be true on presence of `authFlag` key in localStorage, even if the value is `false` however.